# How to subdivide uiimage on tap event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing

I have a image in UIImageView. When user taps one particular area on image, that part of image should be highlighted by a square and the subpart of image in that square should be used for scaling.

How can I do it?

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you tell what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's actually going to involve:

1. user tap gesture handling
2. overlay a UIView for the square to highlight
3. crop and scale the certain area of the original image, you may need some helpers like: https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit